# Run android instrumented test without emulator GUI

Tags: android, xcode, gradle, instrumented-test

I could run Android instrumented tests like this. And an emulator will be opened before test execution.
`./gradlew clean app:connectedVariantNameAndroidTest`

Can we do it without this emulator GUI? Because with Xcode/iOS, I could perform instrumented tests from command line and without Simulator GUI opened. So I'm wondering if we could do the same with  Android.